# is it possible to mass add leads to campaign monitor through salesforce?

Tags: app, campaign

This may be off-topic, but i feel this is the best possible forum for finding a solution:
Using the 3rd party app "`Campaign Monitor`" is it possible to mass add leads (or contacts) to Campaign Monitor within salesforce without having to export the list of leads to a file and upload that way.